# Keras Sequential Dense input layer - and MNIST: why do images need to be reshaped?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer, mnist

I'm asking this because I feel I'm missing something fundamental.

By now most everyone knows that the MNIST images are 28X28 pixels. The [keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/) tells me this about Dense:

> Input shape nD tensor with shape: (batch_size, ..., input_dim). The most common situation would be a 2D input with shape (batch_size, input_dim).

So a newbie like me would assume that the images could be fed to the model as a 28*28 matrix. Yet every tutorial I found goes through various gymasntics to convert the images to a single 784-long feature.

Sometimes by

```
num_pixels = X_train.shape[1] * X_train.shape[2]
model.add(Dense(num_pixels, input_dim=num_pixels, activation='...'))
```

or

```
num_pixels = np.prod(X_train.shape[1:])
model.add(Dense(512, activation='...', input_shape=(num_pixels,)))
```

or

```
model.add(Dense(units=10, input_dim=28*28, activation='...'))
history = model.fit(X_train.reshape((-1,28*28)), ...)
```

or even:

```
model = Sequential([Dense(32, input_shape=(784,)), ...),])
```

So my question is simply - why? Can't Dense just accept an image as-is or, if necessary, just process it "behind the scenes", as it were? And if, as I suspect, this processing has to be done, is any of these methods (or others) inherently preferable?

Comment: Simply no! That's because [currently the Dense layer is applied on the last axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092176/2099607). Therefore, if you feed it an image of shape `(height, width)` or `(height, width, channels)`, Dense layer would only be applied on the last axis (i.e. width or channels).

Comment: Well, I'll be damned! What is the world coming to when a newbie can't even trust the documentation :). Documentation aside, I have to say that those tutorial-posting people out there should have bothered to explain WHY they flattened the images (assuming they themselves knew the reason to begin with) instead of just posting away... Anyway, thanks for this info - can you post is as an actual answer so I can mark it solved? Or is that against the rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested by OP (i.e. Original Poster), I will mention the answer I gave in my comment and elaborate more.

> Can't Dense just accept an image as-is or, if necessary, just process
>   it "behind the scenes", as it were?

Simply no! That's because [currently the Dense layer is applied on the last axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092176/2099607). Therefore, if you feed it an image of shape `(height, width)` or `(height, width, channels)`, Dense layer would be only applied on the last axis (i.e. width or channels). However, when the image is flattened, all the units in the Dense layer would be applied on the whole image and each unit is connected to all the pixels with different weights. To further clarify this consider this model:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(10, input_shape=(28*28,)))
model.summary()
```

Model summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                7850      
=================================================================
Total params: 7,850
Trainable params: 7,850
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

As you can see, there are 7850 parameters in the Dense layer: each unit is connected to all the pixels (28*28*10 + 10 bias params = 7850). Now consider this model:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(10, input_shape=(28,28)))
model.summary()
```

Model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 28, 10)            290       
=================================================================
Total params: 290
Trainable params: 290
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

In this case there are only 290 parameters in the Dense layer. Here each unit in the Dense layer is connected to all the pixels as well, but the difference is that the weights are shared across the first axis (28*10 + 10 bias params = 290). It is as though the features are extracted from each row of the image compared to the previous model which extracted features across the whole image. And therefore this (i.e. weight sharing) may or may not be useful for your application.