# AssertionError while trying to concatenate two models and fit in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I'm trying to develop an image captioning model. I'm referring to this [Github repository](https://github.com/jonkuo/Deep-Learning-Image-Captioning). I have three methods, and they perform the following:

1. Generates the image model
2. Generates the caption model
3. Concatenates the image and caption model together

Since the code is long, I've created a [Gist to show the methods](https://gist.github.com/yedhukrishnan/dd64943b4ad8ceec9879feaa31db5f4b).

Here is a [summary of my image model and caption model](https://gist.github.com/yedhukrishnan/45910b044f00220ea6d910576ff40d78).

But then I run the code, I am getting this error:

```
TraceTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "trainer.py", line 99, in <module>
    model.fit([images, encoded_captions], one_hot_captions, batch_size = 1, epochs = 5)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 950, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 671, in _standardize_user_data
    self._set_inputs(x)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 575, in _set_inputs
    assert len(inputs) == 1
AssertionError
```

Since the error is coming from Keras library, I have no idea how to debug this. But something is wrong when I try to concatenate them together.

I would like to know if I'm missing something here

Comment: is it the last version what I found here: "image_captioning.py"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the get the outputs of the models, using `output` attribute, and then use [Keras functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) to be able to concatenate them (by either of [`Concatenate`](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#concatenate) layer or its equivalent functional interface [`concatenate`](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#concatenate_1)) and create the final model:

```
from keras.models import Model

image_model = get_image_model()
language_model = get_language_model(vocab_size)

merged = concatenate([image_model.output, language_model.output])
x = LSTM(256, return_sequences = False)(merged)
x = Dense(vocab_size)(x)
out = Activation('softmax')(x)

model = Model([image_model.input, language_model.input], out)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
model.fit([images, encoded_captions], one_hot_captions, ...)
```

As it is now in your code, you can also define a function for the model creation logic:

```
def get_concatenated_model(image_model, language_model, vocab_size):
    merged = concatenate([image_model.output, language_model.output])
    x = LSTM(256, return_sequences = False)(merged)
    x = Dense(vocab_size)(x)
    out = Activation('softmax')(x)

    model = Model([image_model.input, language_model.input], out)
    return model
```

Comment: That helped to fix the issue. Thank you! I have another question. My output has to be a time distributed one, because I have more than one word as the caption. Here, the expected output shape is ```(None, 2327)```, but I need ```(None, 41, 2327)```. 41 is the maximum length. I tried to add a ```TimeDistributed``` layer, but that didn't work as expected. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @YedhuKrishnan You are almost there: no need for a `TimeDistributed` layer, since [Dense layer is applied on the last axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092176/2099607). Just set  `return_sequences=True` in the LSTM layer.

Comment: @today , could you please write the similar function but using the sequential Keras API?

Comment: @Ghanem You can't do that since Sequential API can be used for sequential models, i.e. one layer is directly connected to the previous layer. Therefore, when there is a concatenation layer, then the model is no longer sequential.

Comment: @today, thanx, but I found many examples where they use the sequential API with, as ex.: https://statcompute.wordpress.com/2017/01/08/an-example-of-merge-layer-in-keras/

Comment: @Ghanem That was in older versions of Keras (I think < 2.0) when there was a `Merge` layer for all kinds of merge operation. In current versions there is no such a layer and each merge operation [has its own separate layer](https://keras.io/layers/merge/). And you can't use them in a Sequential model.