# Keras - Embedding Layer and GRU Layer Shape Error

Tags: python, keras, embedding, keras-layer

```
# input_shape = (137861, 21, 1)
# output_sequence_length = 21
# english_vocab_size = 199
# french_vocab_size = 344

def embed_model(input_shape, output_sequence_length, english_vocab_size, french_vocab_size):
    '''
    Build and train a RNN model using word embedding on x and y
    :param input_shape: Tuple of input shape
    :param output_sequence_length: Length of output sequence
    :param english_vocab_size: Number of unique English words in the dataset
    :param french_vocab_size: Number of unique French words in the dataset
    :return: Keras model built, but not trained
    '''

    learning_rate = 1e-3
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Embedding(english_vocab_size, 128, input_length=output_sequence_length, input_shape=input_shape[1:]))

    model.add(GRU(units=128, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(french_vocab_size)))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    model.summary()

    model.compile(loss=sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
                  optimizer=Adam(learning_rate),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

When invoking this method to train a model, it gets the error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer gru_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

How to fix the shape error between Embedding Layer and GRU Layer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Embedding layer takes a 2D array as the input. However, the shape of the input array is `(137861, 21, 1)` which makes it a 3D array. Simply remove the last axis using [`squeeze()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) method from numpy:

```
data = np.squeeze(data, axis=-1)
```

---

As a side, there is no need to use `TimeDistributed` layer here, since the [Dense layer is applied on the last axis by defualt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092176/2099607).