# ValueError, Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 4 dimensions

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I'm trying to fine-tune a MobileNet but I'm receiving the following error:

```py
ValueError, Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (10, 14)
```

Is there any conflict with how I set my directory iterators?

```py
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input).flow_from_directory(
train_path, target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=10)
valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input).flow_from_directory(
valid_path, target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=10)

test_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input).flow_from_directory(
test_path, target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=10, shuffle=False)
```

and my new bottleneck layer is as follows:

```py
x=mobile.layers[-6].output
predictions = Dense(14, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs=mobile.input, outputs=predictions)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [Dense layer is applied on the last axis of its input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092176/2099607) and considering the fact that `x` is a 4D tensor, the `predictions` tensor would also be a 4D tensor. That's why the model expects a 4D output (i.e. `expected dense_1 to have 4 dimensions`) but your labels are 2D (i.e. `but got array with shape (10, 14)`). To resolve this, you need to make `x` as a 2D tensor. One way of doing it is to use a `Flatten` layer:

```py
x = mobile.layers[-6].output
x = Flatten()(x)
predictions = Dense(14, activation='softmax')(x)
```