# Problem with dimensions of input array in Keras (TF) with CNN to play chess

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, python-chess

I want to feed a numpy array into a CNN, that contains 2 chess positions, one before a move and the second after a certain move. I want to train the CNN to estimate the evaluation of that move by a conventional chess program. These evaluations are int values.

The shapes of the `x` and `y` are: `x: (2000000, 8, 8, 2) , y: (2000000,)`

The model code:

```py
#define model
model = Sequential()
#model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu', input_dim=864))

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', input_shape=(8,8,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', init='uniform'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam',metrics=['mae'])
print(model.summary())
```

The training is done with:

```py
history = model.fit(x, y, validation_split=0.1, epochs=5, batch_size=20000, verbose=2)
```

It gives me the following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-619de3f1be1b> in <module>()
    171         for i in range(5):
    172             print("Fitting begins", x.shape, y.shape)
--> 173             history = model.fit(x, y, validation_split=0.1, epochs=5, batch_size=20000, verbose=2)
    174             #score = model.evaluate(x, y, verbose=2)
    175             #print(score)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    950             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    951             class_weight=class_weight,
--> 952             batch_size=batch_size)
    953         # Prepare validation data.
    954         do_validation = False

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    787                 feed_output_shapes,
    788                 check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 789                 exception_prefix='target')
    790 
    791             # Generate sample-wise weight values given the `sample_weight` and

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    126                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    127                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 128                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    129                 if not check_batch_axis:
    130                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_10 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (2000000, 1)
```

What do I do wrong? How can I fix this?

---

OK, I realized that the problem is related to the output shape of the last layer:

```py
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)           (None, 6, 6, 128)         2432      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)           (None, 4, 4, 128)         147584    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_14 (Dense)             (None, 4, 4, 128)         16512     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_7 (Batch (None, 4, 4, 128)         512       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_15 (Dense)             (None, 4, 4, 1)           129       
=================================================================
```

But why is it `(None, 4, 4, 1)`? Shouldn't it be `(None, 1)`? It's a single neuron with 1 value!

Answer (score 1):

> But why is it (None, 4, 4, 1)? Shouldn't it be (None, 1) ???

No, it shouldn't. Because the [Dense layer is applied on the last axis of its input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092176/2099607), and therefore since in this case it is applied on the output of `Conv2D` layer, which is is a 4D tensor, the output of the `Dense` layer would also be 4D tensor. To resolve this, you can first flatten the output of `Conv2D` layer using a `Flatten` layer and then use the `Dense` layer, like this:

```py
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())  # flatten the output of `Conv2D` to a 2D tensor
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', init='uniform'))
```