# How to get only last output of sequence model in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I trained a Many-to-Many sequence model in Keras with `return_sequences=True` and `TimeDistributed` wrapper on the last Dense layer:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=50))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')))
# train...
model.save_weights("weights.h5")
```

[image]

So during the training the loss is calculated over all hidden states (in every timestamp). But for inference I only need the get output on the last timestamp. So I load the weights into Many-to-One sequence model for inference without `TimeDistributed` wrapper and I set `return_sequences=False` to get only last output of the LSTM layer:

```
inference_model = Sequential()
inference_model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=50))
inference_model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=False))
inference_model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))

inference_model.load_weights("weights.h5")
```

When I test my inference model on a sequence with length 20 I expect to get a prediction with shape (vocab_size) but `inference_model.predict(...)` still returns predictions for every timestamp - a tensor of shape (20, vocab_size)

Comment: As already stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092176/2099607), `TimeDistributed(Dense(...))` and `Dense(...)` are equivalent, since `Dense` layer is applied on the last dimension of its input Tensor.

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing "samples" (dimension 0) with "time steps" ( dimension 1)?

Answer (score 2):

If, for whatever reason, you need only the last timestep during inference, you can build a new model which applies the trained model on the input and returns the last timestep as its output using the `Lambda` layer:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda

inp = Input(shape=put_the_input_shape_here)
x = model(inp) # apply trained model on the input
out = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,-1])(x)

inference_model = Model(inp, out)
```

---

**Side Note:** As already stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092176/2099607), `TimeDistributed(Dense(...))` and `Dense(...)` are equivalent, since `Dense` layer is applied on the last dimension of its input Tensor. Hence, that's why you get the same output shape.

Comment: Oh. Is there a way to apply TimeDistributed(Dense(...)) to every timestamp of LSTM output?

Comment: @nidomo Well, I am not sure what you mean exactly as it is already applied on all the timesteps.