# Dense vs. TimeDistributed(Dense)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, tf.keras

Is there any difference between this two methods of using `Dense` layer? Seems output shape is the same and number of parameters is the same.

1. Will be the output the same if we use fixed weights?
2. Will be the result the same during training?

```
def test_rnn_output_v1():

    max_seq_length = 10
    n_features = 8
    rnn_dim = 64
    dense_dim = 16

    input = Input(shape=(max_seq_length, n_features))
    out = LSTM(rnn_dim, return_sequences=True)(input)
    out = Dense(dense_dim)(out)

    model = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=out)

    print(model.summary())

    # (None, max_seq_length, n_features)
    # (None, max_seq_length, dense_dim)

def test_rnn_output_v2():

    max_seq_length = 10
    n_features = 8
    rnn_dim = 64
    dense_dim = 16

    input = Input(shape=(max_seq_length, n_features))
    out = LSTM(rnn_dim, return_sequences=True)(input)
    out = TimeDistributed(Dense(dense_dim))(out)

    model = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=out)

    print(model.summary())

    # (None, max_seq_length, n_features)
    # (None, max_seq_length, dense_dim)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between `TimeDistributed(Dense(...))` and `Dense(...)` and they have exactly the same output dimension and connectivity. That's because the `Dense` layer is applied on the last axis of its input; therefore, it does not make a difference if it's wrapped in a `TimeDistributed` layer or not. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092176/2099607) explains the workings of `Dense` layer in more detail.