# How can I load a Pandas DataFrame into a LSTM model?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm just playing with RNN's and was having trouble getting my data into the right format for my model. I have the following dataframe:

```
    Apple   Pears   Oranges ID
0   1.00    2.09    4.11    0
1   1.38    1.73    5.13    1
2   1.68    2.28    6.91    2
3   1.50    2.69    8.93    3
4   1.35    2.63    12.25   4
5   1.52    3.09    12.20   5
6   1.63    3.63    13.68   6
7   2.01    4.92    16.21   7
8   2.52    4.01    18.79   8
9   3.10    5.49    24.05   9
```

`ID` is a order/timesteps for my data.

I ran this command to try to load it into a timeseries dataset:

```
Dataset = keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(priceHistorydf, basketHistorydf, sequence_length=10)
```

But when I try to train a model on this, I get the following error:

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

X_train = priceHistorydf
y_train = basketHistorydf

model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(10), input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:])))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(8)))

model.add(Dense(8, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[-1], activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="adam")

# history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=2, batch_size=8)
history = model.fit(Dataset, epochs=2, batch_size=8)
```

Error:

```
 ValueError: `TimeDistributed` Layer should be passed an `input_shape ` with at least 3 dimensions, received: [None, 4]
```

I'm just guessing but I realize I did not explicitly let the model know that `ID` is the timestep; but I'm unsure how to pass it to the model with my dataframe.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are setting the `input_shape` argument incorrectly (i.e. `X_train` is the original data, and not the generated timeseries; hence `X_train.shape[1:]` is not correct as the input shape). Since you have used `sequence_lenght=10` and each timestep has 3 features, therefore we should have `input_shape=(10,3)` (of course, assuming you would remove the `ID` column from the data first, because that's not a feature per say).

**As a side note:** the `Dense(...)` and `TimeDistributed(Dense(...))` are exactly the same, because the `Dense` layer is applied on the last axis by default. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092176/2099607) for more information and explanation.

Comment: Thank you. Some the tutorials aren’t really clear to me. Is the order of the time series inferred by the order of the dataframe or do I need to explicitly state the order / time steps ?

Comment: @Lostsoul The order of timesteps is the same as the order of rows in the dataframe. Read the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/timeseries_dataset_from_array) of this function for more information and how it works.